# Adding Control Properties in C# with drop down menu

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes, properties

I have this properties with default value. Can anyone help me on how to have a drop down menu for choices on values?. I want the values on the drop down only appears `1-10` only...

```
private int _margin = 10;

[Bindable(true), Category(_category), DefaultValue(10)]
public int MarginWidth
{
    get { return _margin; }
    set { _margin = Math.Abs(value); Invalidate(); }
}
```

[image: img]

Anyway, how do you call this `[Bindable(true), Category(_category), DefaultValue(10)]`
just a key for google searching for reference?

Comment: sorry i used it as an example.. actually i want to add a Control Property like ButtonSet: then in dropdown menu, there's options "Set A", "Set B", "Set C".. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the items in the square brackets are [`Attribute`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx), eg. [`BindableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx), [`CategoryAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) and [`DefaultValueAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx).

In a nutshell, attributes are used to attach [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) to methods. What information is totally definable by the creator of the attribute. These attributes can be obtained again via reflection and their data accessed. The documentation for the `Attribute` class linked above has a lot of information about usage, etc.

Comment: can i ask sample code for binding multiple data in Control Property?

Comment: @vrynxzent: I haven't done much with creating my own `Control`s, so I can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: @vrynxzent: The best bet would be to look at the `System.ComponentModel.*Attribute` classes and see if there's anything there that can help you because I think you're almost on the right track here.

Comment: @vrynxzent: You're really asking two unrelated questions in one here, it may pay for you to move the other question into a seperate one.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys.. i found the answer.. :) im using this one.. public enum PanelSet
    {
        Active,
        Inactive,
    }                      public PanelSet PanelSet
        {
            get { return _set; }
            set { _set = value; Invalidate(); }
        }